# UIBarButtonItem don't work on tap

Tags: ios, triggers, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I get some problem to trigger my toolbar button on my datepicker. My datepicker is showing perfectly but when i click on done item button nothing append in log . I don't know why it's not working.

any help would be appreciated :)

```
-(void) dismiss:(id){
  NSLog("test");
}

-(IBAction) datePicker:(id)sender{
  ...
  ...
  UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
  toolBar.tag = 1;
  toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

  UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
  UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss:)];
  [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
}
```

Comment: Try to modify the first line to this: - (void)dismiss:(UIBarButtonItem *) button

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: no, i don't get any exception.

Comment: always same result when i change to  - (void)dismiss:(UIBarButtonItem *) button

Comment: `NSLog("test")` looks strange to me - shouldn't it contain `@`: `NSLog(@"test");` ?

Comment: Your right @Lanorkin but actually there is code in  -(void) dismiss:(id) but i resume by a simple test log. But "XXX" work too and it's in char* and @"XXX" is in string objective-c format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally **found** an **alternative**, the **solution** is to use **through** a **textfield** like this code:

*I use **ARC***

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [UIToolbar alloc] init];     
UITextField * textfield = [[UITextField alloc]init];
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init]];

toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

textField.inputView = datePicker;
textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
[self.view addSubview:textfield];
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope this work for you too.